# Make Exoplayer Closed Captions (CEA-608) appear at the bottom

Tags: android, exoplayer, exoplayer2.x

how can I make Exoplayer Closed Captions (CEA-608) appear at the bottom like the regular subtitles? Now they appear at the place on screen where character talks.
I tried:

```
exoView.getSubtitleView().setTextAlignment(View.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_CENTER);
```

But it is not working.
I need them to appear at the bottom.
SubtitleView is regular View, maybe there are some methods for that? I haven't found, please help!